# PDFDocEncoding issue when try to convert PDF figure to TIFF [R and ImageMagick]

Tags: r, pdf, encoding, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I try to convert R-generated PDF figure to TIFF using the [ImageMagick's](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) convert tool. My pipeline goes as follows. First I plot a figure in R:

```
pdf("test.pdf")
hist(rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
```

Then I use convert tool:

```
convert -density 1200 -compress lzw -alpha remove -depth 8 -units PixelsPerInch test.pdf test.tiff
```

But I get the following errors:

```
   **** Error: Invalid BaseEncoding name "PDFDocEncoding" ignoring BaseEncoding.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Invalid BaseEncoding name "PDFDocEncoding" ignoring BaseEncoding.
               Output may be incorrect.
convert-im6.q16: DistributedPixelCache '127.0.0.1' @ error/distribute-cache.c/ConnectPixelCacheServer/244.
convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted `test.tiff' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3982.
```

I'm using Linux machine with R version 3.4.2. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks and sounds odd. Maybe try again but start your command with `convert -debug cache ... as before..`

Comment: I'm guessing your temporary disk space is full, probably `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`. Check the directories that **ImageMagick** looks in when you run the `convert -debug cache ...` command above.